# Win32 program crashes on Windows 8 when calling GetSaveFileName() or SHBrowseForFolder()

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8

I'm maintaining a C++ program that uses Win32.  It's been working fine for years, but now I am having problems with the "select file" or "select folder" functions on 2 computers both running Windows 8, yet not on 2 other computers running Windows 8.

The problem is that the program crashes in the "select file" or "select folder" functions, deep in Microsoft code. It crashes immediately after displaying the dialog, before the user has a chance to touch anything.

I've done a lot of experimentation, and I've got it to randomly work, but then recompiling the same code will make the bug reappear.  Finally I produced a tiny program that calls the function 10 times in succession, without any other code, and the first time always succeeds but the 2nd time the program crashes.  Linked in with my full program, it sometimes crashes on the first call, sometimes on the 2nd.  My code is below:

```
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE _hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR args, int nCmdShow)
{   
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    OPENFILENAME OFN;
    char buf[1024];

    memset(&OFN, 0, sizeof(OFN));
    OFN.lStructSize = sizeof(OFN);
    OFN.hwndOwner = NULL;
    OFN.hInstance = NULL;
    OFN.lpstrFilter = "PTN files\0*.ptn\0\0\0";//overkill
    OFN.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    OFN.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
    OFN.nFilterIndex = 1;
    OFN.nMaxFile = sizeof(buf);
    OFN.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    OFN.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    OFN.lpstrTitle = NULL;
    OFN.nFileOffset = 0;
    OFN.nFileExtension = 0;
    OFN.lpstrDefExt = "ptn";
    OFN.lCustData = 0;
    OFN.lpfnHook = 0;
    OFN.lpTemplateName = NULL;
    OFN.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    strcpy(buf, "\0");//overkill
    OFN.lpstrFile = buf;
    OFN.Flags = OFN_LONGNAMES | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_EXPLORER;
    //NB: tried both with and without OFN_EXPLORER
    GetSaveFileName(&OFN);
}
return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the stack trace when it crashes?

Comment: Try disabling shell extensions on the machines which fail

Comment: str s, argv[130], argc are unnecessary, also needs an #include "windows.h" and a closing brace at the end of the example to compile properly.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using the legacy GetSaveFileNameA function rather than using UNICODE?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you elaborate?  How do I disable shell extensions?  How do I know which ones are failing? (Feel free to convert your comment to an answer).

Comment: There are tools around that allow you to temporarily disable shell extensions. For instance: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html  It's just a hunch that a shell extension is screwing with your program

Comment: Try changing the file filter to `"PTN files|*.ptn"`

Comment: I ran your program and it did not crash. Please include a stack trace with public symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any error in your code.
I doubt that anybody will be able to answer your question.

Just some ideas:

1.)
You compile your project as MBCS ?
Does Windows 8 still support that Ansi stuff ?
Did you try if the same happens with the Unicode version?

2.)
I have had also a lot of troubles with these functions already in Windows XP.
They are definitely buggy and it seems that in Windows 8 they are still or even more. I found out for example that an invalid value for lpstrFile may result in the dialog not opening. Also other parameters are critical.

3.)
What value did you define for **_WIN32_WINNT** ?
I recommend at least 0x0502 or higher to assure that OPENFILENAME structure is not a version from the age of Windows NT which might not be supported on Windows 8.

4.)
What happens if you try out the MFC version:

```
CFileDialog dlg(FALSE);
dlg.DoModal();
```

Let all parameters in their default value. If this works you know that it is not a Windows 8 bug. Then study what parameters differ in the OFN from your code. Also have a look at the value of `sizeof(OFN)` which may influence the behavior of Windows 8.

5.) It may be required that your application / Dll has an embedded manifest for Shell32 to work correctly.

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' processorArchitecture='X86'   name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

6.)
If all this does not help you have to experiment until you found what parameter causes the problem: Is hwndOwner required on Windows 8 ? Is hInstance required on Windows 8 ? Is there a flag missing ? Is lpstrInitialDir required ?

7.) I have had very very weird crashes that happened from time to time, very difficult to reproduce. After WEEKS of frustrating search I finally found out that this is a bug in Visual Studio. The solution to avoid the crashy code was to select "**Re**build Solution" in the menu of Visual Studio. I have this effect only in one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing up David Heffernan's answer which he provided as a question comment. (David, if you provide a proper answer, I'll upvote it and try to delete this one).

"Try disabling shell extensions on the machines which fail. There are tools around that allow you to temporarily disable shell extensions. For instance: nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html It's just a hunch that a shell extension is screwing with your program."

Comment: I tried this on one computer.  She hasn't installed much. I disabled all non-Microsoft shell extensions. Still got the same problem.  I chickened out of disabling all shell extensions because I got a message that scared me off doing this.